# ActiveState Perl PPM can't add repo due to Certificate Verify Failed

Tags: perl, activestate

When running the ActiveState Perm Package Manager I try and add a repository but I get the error: certificate Verify Failed. The repository is on a web site for which there is no way I can verify it's certificate. I will answer my own question in a minute because it took me forever to find the solution and I thought the community might benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the environment variable: PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME with a value of 0

Comment: You might want to make this answer a little prettier and then accept it yourself once the time is up.